# swift CocoaAsyncSocket connectToHost method arguments error

Tags: ios, swift, asyncsocket, cocoaasyncsocket

I define properties as bellow:

```
let addr:String = "192.168.31.218"
let port :UInt16 = 8000
let timeout:Double = 5.0
var socket: GCDAsyncSocket!
var errPtr : NSError?
```

and I call the method as bellow:

> socket.connectToHost(addr, onPort: port, withTimeout: timeout, error:&errPtr)

The xcode7 reminder me:

> Cannot invoke 'connectToHost' with an argument list of type '(NSString, onPort: UInt16, withTimeout: Double, error: inout NSError?)'

The method signature is:

> - (BOOL)connectToHost:(NSString *)hostname
>                onPort:(UInt16)port
>           withTimeout:(NSTimeInterval)timeout
>                 error:(NSError **)errPtr

It is strange that it works in xcode6.4 with swift1.2, but now I upgrade it in xcode7 with swift2.0. Above error happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this!!

```
    do {
        try socket.connectToHost(addr, onPort: port, withTimeout: timeout)
    } catch let e {
        print(e)
    }
```

It's working for me.(Xcode:7 or later, CocoaAsyncSocket: 7.4.2)